# Google maps API link gives error

Tags: javascript

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

I get a "Script error", if I try to run it. It is in a html document which is called from another program. I'm running windows 10, and my default web browser is Firefox 55.0.3 (64-bit)

Comment: The script contains Javascript which is bad. You do not provide a lot to go on.

Comment: It's likely because you are missing an api key. The google maps api v3 requires you to register your app (or developer account, I think- for free!) to use their APIs

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error), it seems that you have a `MissingKeyMapError` -

```
"The script element that loads the API is missing the required authentication parameter. If you are using the standard Maps JavaScript API, you must use a key parameter with a valid API key. If you are a Premium Plan customer, you must use either a client parameter with your client ID or a key parameter with a valid API key."
```

Get an API key from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

Answer (score 0):

For many years Google allowed us to use Maps without an API key but now we can test local without an API key but when we'll use Google Maps API scripts on the internet in our projects, we're in need of a API key, Please, request an API key, don't forget to add domains that are allowed to use it and add it to your script.. Again: You can have [25.000 maps impressions per 24 hours](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) for free so you might want to allow your domain(s) only..

[Enable or request your API key here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I hope this is helpful and will bring you into the right direction..

Comment: Below is the full program: I have amended the line to include an API key. Now it "crashes" on line 56 Character 9 with "google is undefined", if I then contine to run the program I get the following error: "Script error: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBE3ulDpKbqw7hSTViIj6CIdWyAASm2_BM&callback=initMap.

Comment: Below is NOT the full program, as there is insufficient space to include it all. I realise that one line of code out of context is useless, but if it is allowed, I would gladly post a link to my dropbox, from which the whole file can be retrieved. It's only 50+ lines long.

Comment: If you add an API key from google it can take up to 24 hours to get it to work, please be patient, if the key is older and it's not working there must be something wrong, Please post your code including everything that is related to this issue to your question. With 1 line of code only, we can't post the best available answer in order to solve the issue as there might be important information in your code where it's going wrong I'm sure there are a lot of people who can help you if you do so and it will solve the issue faster. Did you run your script on a local server and did the  Map show up?

Comment: I have run out of patience (in fact I ran out yesterday, but I've been busy!).To answer your last question first, yes I did, and it doesn't bring up a map, but the "script" behind the map (if you see what I mean).

Comment: (Contd) The program immediately fails again with another script error. "Line 0. Character 0. Script Error. Code 0. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBE3ulDpKbqw7hSTViIj6CIdWyAASm2_BM&callback=initMap. Take the yes option again and the program runs except there is NO map and another script error. "Line 49. Character 13. Unable to get property 'setPosition' of undefined or null reference". Code 0. File:///C;/Program Files (x86)/mapview.htm. The full code is in the following comments. 5 files of 10 line (no blank lines) and a final file.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map_canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

Comment: height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBE3ulDpKbqw7hSTViIj6CIdWyAASm2_BM&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
    </script>
    <script>
        var map;
        var Point;
        var customMarker;

Comment: function initialize() {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507222, -0.1275);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 17,
                center: myLatLng,
                zoomControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
                },
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

Comment: };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('marker_car.png',
                new google.maps.Size(38, 32),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(19, 16)
            );
            customMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,

Comment: title: "Car Marker",
                icon: image,
                optimized: false
            });
        }
        function DrawCurrent(x, y) {
            var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(y, x);
            customMarker.setPosition(LatLng);
            map.panTo(LatLng);
        }

Comment: google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>        P.S. I've taken a blank line out at position 40, so for 49 above read 48. If you can help that would be terrific. Most grateful. Just to clarify. I have rum this script in windows 10, with two versions of Firefox (the latest, and one much older), and in windows 8 with firefox, old version. All with the same results.

Comment: Please provide all code that is related to the Google Maps, did you test your script on a local server? if not please test on a local server, if you don't have a local server please install [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org) on a computer or another good server you like to test it, if it does work on a local server there IS something wrong with your key, #1 you didn't allow your domain or made a typo or some other issue.. Please check for typos in your API account as well..